# Controller with filter and multiple views

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, filtering

in my controller i have two functions `index` and `archiv`
in both functions i have the same set of filter conditions, but for the archiv function I use the view of index. what to do to set conditions in combination with render-function. do you have any hint on how to solve this problem

```
public function index() {
    ...
    $this->set('events', $this->Paginator->paginate($cond));
```

-

```
public function archiv() {

    ...
    $this->render('index');     // reuse index view

    // is not working
    // $this->set('events', $this->Paginator->paginate($cond));
```

**edit**: if I copy the view index.cpt, and comment the `$this->render` and uncomment the last line of archiv, it works fine, but i'd rather keep just one view, since `archiv` is always the same as `index`

Comment: what cake version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the variables before you call the render function:

```
public function archiv() {

...
// this should work now
$this->set('events', $this->Paginator->paginate($cond));
$this->render('index');     // reuse index view
```